# How to create a fence by adding loop cuts to existing cylinder shape

Tags: edit-mode

I want to model the safety fence on a floating dock which is constructed with steel tubes welded together.
I have created the top and sides and now want to model the extra tubes as per the image below.
Watching a youtube tutorial on joining cylinders I feel that all I need to do is to add loop cuts at the appropriate places, select the relevant face(s) and then extrude along normals but can't work out how to add the loop cuts in the correct locations and add two at each place the width of the cylinder.
I am not interested in modelling weld marks.
Mayber it would be easier just to add extra (cylinder) meshes?

Firstly a photo of the real object -
[image]

Now what I want to do

[image]

[image]

Comment: As all the tube is of the same dimension, the shipped add-on Add Mesh: Extra Objects > Pipe Joints becomes a quick route. That reduces the problem to cutting loops in the original in the right places, snapping, extruding and welding. No time to answer just now, but will get to it of someone else doesn't. (The original is 0.025 radius, 8-sided)

Comment: Thanks Robin. I tried your suggestion but (not having used pipe joints before) had problems right from the starts as 'horizontal' pipe had incorrect geometry. Anyway moonboots has offered a suggestion below which looks ok.

Comment: I'll leave it to the maestro, then :) ( I did manage to do it reasonably quickly.. but a description of all the sneaky selection/snapping/modifier tricks would be quite lengthy.  And @moonboots usually finds the simplest way to good topology for subdiv. much more quickly than me :)  )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could duplicate this edge loop:

[image]

Extrude it until it crosses the bar:

[image]

Select the horizontal cylinder and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Intersect (Boolean)*:

[image]

Choose *Union* in the *Operator Box*:

[image]

Select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* so that the overlapping vertices merge, add some support edge loops, slide the edge loops, slide with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, press <kbd>E</kbd> to parallelize to the next edge loop, <kbd>F</kbd> to parallelize to the opposite:

[image]

Animated gif:

[image]

My *Snap To* panel settings:

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151964/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-how-to-create-a-fence-by-adding-loop-cuts-to-e); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.